# Smooth join spline tube to square edge

Tags: edges

In Blender I have these tubes I created using splines setting resolution 6 and a depth. Now at the end of the tubes I need them to become square so that they will fit or blend nice to the end of the square pieces. Can I somehow move the individual vertices or does Blender have a function that can automatically match /smooth the end of the two objects.
[image: Tubes and square edges]

Comment: Quick answer, look into the Loft feature of the LoopTools addon?

Comment: have you tried to join the square + round pipes, then use W > LoopTools > Bridge?

Comment: I have tried the bridge, but which meshes should I select, I triend to select the last ring of meshes on the pipe and the square, but it just removes some of them and others are joint in a single vertx.

Comment: I gave up and just manipulated the individual vertices, took some time, but now I am done. Thanks for your input, Blender has a very steep learning curve. Some of those advanced tools, you need to know if to select vertices, edges or faces, what to select and what not to selec. Just like the Bevel tool. If you do not know exactly what to select and what to edit, everything turns into spaghetti.